# How to implement Infinite Scrolling for AngularJS & MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created one angular JS application using MVC 4

where i created one view which renders templates in that we have one template which contains large amount of data as one lack records for that i am looking to implement Infinite Scrolling

1.index.cshtml

```
<div id="sidebar-left" class="span2">
    <div class="nav-collapse sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu">
            <li class="navbar-brand"><a href="/Events/Talks">Talks</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-brand"><a href="/Events/SRDNames">SRDNames</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-brand"><a href="/Events/Speakers">Speakers</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-brand"><a href="/Events/AddTalk">Add Talk</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. SRDNames.cshtml

   ```
     <div class="box-content">
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
       <tr>
           <th>
               SRD_NAME
           </th>
           <th>
               CREATED_BY_USER_ID
           </th>
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="srdname in srdnames">
           <td>
               {{srdname.sRD_NAME}}
           </td>
           <td>
               {{srdname.cREATED_BY_USER_ID}}
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   ```

3.eventModule.js

```
   var eventModule = angular.module("eventModule", []).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        //Path - it should be same as href link
        $routeProvider.when('/Events/Talks', { templateUrl: '/Templates/Talk.html', controller: 'eventController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Events/Speakers', { templateUrl: '/Templates/Speaker.html', controller: 'speakerController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Events/AddTalk', { templateUrl: '/Templates/AddTalk.html', controller: 'talkController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Events/SRDNames', { templateUrl: '/Templates/SRDNames.html', controller: 'srdnamescontroller' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

4. srdnamescontroller.js

   ```
   eventModule.controller("srdnamescontroller", function ($scope, EventsService) {
   EventsService.getSRDName().then(function (srdnames) { $scope.srdnames = srdnames }, function ()
   { alert('error while fetching talks from server') })
   ```

   });

5.EventsService.js

```
eventModule.factory("EventsService", function ($http, $q) {
    return {

        getSRDName: function () {
            // Get the deferred object
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            // Initiates the AJAX call
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/events/GetSRDName' }).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
            // Returns the promise - Contains result once request completes
            return deferred.promise;
        },

});
```

looking to implement like http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/ in above application.. please help

Comment: You already have a working example, what exactly are you asking for help for? There are a few elements to infinite scroll: a) Knowing when the user scrolls close to or to the bottom b) Performing some action when that occurs. 

The code you linked is a minimal example of those two things. Where are they supposed to happen in your app?

Comment: Yes that already working code i am confused how it will fit in my structure. in working example its array and the are auto generating some ids and displaying in my case i have set of data how i will process that i am not getting.

Comment: Just a note that ``$http`` returns a promise so in your service you can just do ``return $http(...)``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s4onnn5c/5/)

There are many possible solutions. Here is one that may work for you.
Implement a scroll module that defines the following:

1. An infiniteScroll directive
2. A data service to get the scrollable data

You can use the scroll module from within your app:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div infinite-scroll="items">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['scroll']);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.items = [];
    dataService.loadMore($scope.items, function(lastItem) {
        var items = [];
        var id = lastItem ? lastItem.id : 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            items.push({id: id + i});
        }
        return items;
    });
});
```

The dataService exposes a `loadMore` method that accepts an array, and a callback function to load more data. The above example loads more data by looping through 5 items, and adding to the array.  But you can customize this function callback to retrieve data from another service:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['scroll']);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http, dataService) {
    $scope.items = [];
    dataService.loadMore($scope.items, function(lastItem, done) {
          var lastItemId = lastItem ? lastItem.id : '';
          $http({ method: 'GET',url:'api/items/' + lastItemId})
               .success(function(items) {
                   done(items);
                });            
    });
});
```